# Linq Conditional DefaultIfEmpty query filter

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-query-syntax

I have a query as below:

```
bool variable = false//or true


var query = from e in _repository.GetAll<Entity>()
            from u in e.Users
            where (e.AuditQuestionGroupId != null ? e.AuditQuestionGroupId : 0) == this.LoggedInEntity.AuditQuestionGroupId
            from p in e.PractitionerProfiles.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { entity = e, user = u, profile = p };
```

This works correctly. However, I have a boolean variable that should determine whether the join to e.PractitionerProfiles should have DefaultIfEmpty, thereby making it a Left Outer Join instead of an Inner Join.

However, as I am using annoymous objects, I can't figure out how to do it correctly. So I want the ability to switch between Left and Inner Join without duplicating the whole query like:

```
if(variable) {
            var query = from e in _repository.GetAll<Entity>()
                        from u in e.Users
                        where (e.AuditQuestionGroupId != null ? e.AuditQuestionGroupId : 0) == this.LoggedInEntity.AuditQuestionGroupId
                        from p in e.PractitionerProfiles
                        select new { entity = e, user = u, profile = p };
}
else {
            var query = from e in _repository.GetAll<Entity>()
                        from u in e.Users
                        where (e.AuditQuestionGroupId != null ? e.AuditQuestionGroupId : 0) == this.LoggedInEntity.AuditQuestionGroupId
                        from p in e.PractitionerProfiles.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new { entity = e, user = u, profile = p };
}
```

Is there a clean way to do it with one query? The problem also is that I have a number of further conditions which get placed on it, so declaring query inside the loop means it doesn't have a local variable and I don't know how to create an empty IQueryable anonymous object.

Comment: i can't try this at the moment but can you use the tertiary operator inline? `DefaultIfEmpty` should have the same type as the sequence you call it on.

Comment: See error I get below

Comment: Ah, EF doesn't know what to do with it. Unless you're willing to bring back the entire `PractitionerProfiles` collection from the database up front, I think your copy/pasted query is going to be your best bet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding the filter after the initial query, checking if the e.PractitionerProfiles were null.

```
    var query = from e in _repository.GetAll<Entity>()
                from u in e.Users
                where (e.AuditQuestionGroupId != null ? e.AuditQuestionGroupId : 0) == this.LoggedInEntity.AuditQuestionGroupId
                from p in e.PractitionerProfiles.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { entity = e, user = u, profile = p };
```

then

```
if (variable)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.profile != null);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not use ternary operator?

```
from p in (variable ? e.PractitionerProfiles : e.PractitionerProfiles.DefaultIfEmpty())
```

Comment: I get the following error:
'The nested query is not supported. Operation1='Case' Operation2='Collect''

Comment: @RhysStephens: Try getting the profiles outside the query. Maybe enumerate them before.